# OpenCV - Partial Image Matching

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm new to computer vision and I want to implement image search and matching algorithm where the matching is not necessarily the exact match, but a partial region from it. 

For example: I have a database of cars, and the input image contains a car (which is ROI), the match may not be the exact image but any image of this car (see below): 
input image (i'm targeting the Porsche in front):
[image]

I want the possible match to be something like that (this is not the same car but the closest I could find to illustrate my question): 
[image]

I decided to start with OpenCV libraries in Python. Is my question possible to implement? if yes then please guide me to any useful information to start.

Comment: @BhargavRao Yes i have learned the basics and some image processing techniques, all from OpenCV-Python official tutorial.

Comment: you can try a lot open source tutorials in this area, a great one is this one http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html but is 100% possible

Comment: @jycr753 it's all good, images are shown without links. Thank you I'm aware of Template Matching but haven't tested it yet. But doesn't Template Matching require the exact match (the template) where in my case I want any similar match with similar object.

Comment: this depends on your intended application, specifically real time or no speed requirements.

Comment: Do you aim to match only cars ? or something else ?

Comment: @chris it will be real time

Comment: @dervish no not cars only, I just used it to illustrate my question. I intend to match fashion items (i.e: image of celeb and try to find what she\he is wearing)

Comment: template match is ok IF you don't have a transform as (scale, rotation, different points of view ), I think you need as well to detect a human body before any other process, this will help you to determine the bounds of your aimed target. we can see also my answer

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to use Matching features (keypoints)  approaches, they are scale-invariant features (SIFT) and Speeded Up Robust Features (SURF). A lot of examples are available on Opencv docs, you can check [this one](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography)

Another alternative is proposed in [this paper](http://www.willowgarage.com/sites/default/files/orb_final.pdf):

If you have a predefined reference images, it's efficient to use detection approaches using cascade classifiers, well implemented with opencv.

You can integrate Cascade Classifier of opencv ([here is tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html)), (it is also useful to detect a part of human body)

Opencv provides few xml files already trained to detect faces, eyes and even body. You may also train for your aimed object to get your own xml files ([here is a tuto](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html?highlight=train%20cascade%20classifier) how to train yours from the scratch)

Comment: thanks, I will be sure to check these methods out and see if they work for me.

Comment: For real time I recommend the use of cascade classifier. they are a bit annoying to train properly but well worth it.